How can they determine a bond upon arrest, prior to first appearance?
I've been looking into the mechanics between Justice and Corrections. I was researching some of the general legal procedures. MY QUESTION IS  WHETHER SOMEBODY CAN BOND OUT OF JAIL BEFORE THEY ATTEND MAGISTRATE COURT? AND IF SO, HOW CAN THEY MANAGE TO DO THAT?

My curiosity raised when I inquired as to whether a person can bail out before attending first appearance court.
To which the answer was 'yes'...
My follow up question was how the bail amount would be determined without a judge first reviewing the accusations and setting it accordingly?
The answer kept circling back around to the Magistrate Judge no matter how clearly I rephrased the question.

HOW IS A BOND AMOUNT DETERMINED WITHOUT A JUDGE FIRST SETTING AN AMOUNT?
I've found enough information surrounding this topic already. But this is still unclear. If THIS doesn't make my question clear enough, there's nothing else I can do...

In whichever country's legal system you are asking about (please tag the question to indicate this), is there perhaps a difference between an accused's first appearance in court and a judge reviewing some details to set bail?

Are you trying to ask a question about the law or is this a rant about AI? The majority of the question seems to be the latter.

No. The last paragraph was the ladder of the question. I wasn't ranting about A.I. as much as trying to explain the situation that brought me to ask the question on this platform. I'm not sure what wasnt clear about the question. I would like to know how it's possible for someone to bail out of jail before attending first appearance court, which is when the judge determines your bond status...

The last item with the rant about AI seems disjointed. Is it there because all other items are from an AI conversation? FWIW, if that is the case perhaps you should revisit the „if" before trying to learn all the "how".

SE has a general prohibition against AI content. This most prominently applies to answers generated by AI, but also includes AI-related content in the question. Whatever you learned or didn't learn from your AI query is unimportant to the question here.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
